# AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'bind'

Tags: python, sockets

here is my code:

```
import sae
import socket, sys
host = ''
port = 5005
def app(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(2)
    while 1:
        client, addr = s.accept();
        print("Got connection from ", addr);
        while 1:
            print("the word you want to send:")
            buf = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
            if not buf:
                break
            client.send(bytes(buf, 'UTF-8'))
            data = client.recv(1024);
            if data:
                print(data)
    return ['Hello, world!']

application = sae.create_wsgi_app(app)
```

but I am getting an Attribute Error that says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/sae/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sae/__init__.py", line 18, in
   new_app
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "/data1/www/htdocs/850/love2note/1/index.wsgi", line 11, in app
    s.bind((host, port))
AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

I really do not understand what I need to do to solve this issue. If anyone can please help me, I'll be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

`import sae` you mean [Sina App Engine](http://sae.sina.com.cn/)?

if True:
  bind is not allowed by SAE. [API](http://sae.sina.com.cn/doc/python/socket.html#api)